# do mysql's FOR UPDATE / LOCK IN SHARE MODE also lock future rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, locking, innodb

So, let's say I have a single column that is built over an other table's contents. For example, a list of `students` that belong to the course `3` that I want to cache/prefetch for whatever reason into the `courses` table:

```
students:
ID| name  | courseID
1 | Jerry | 3
2 | Tom   | 3
3 | Mike  | 4
4 | Mary  | 3

courses:
ID| name         | studentsCache
1 | HTML Course  | Jerry, Tom, Mary


$students_rs = $db->get("SELECT name FROM students WHERE courseID = 3");
$studentsList = implode(", ", $students_rs);
$db->exec("UPDATE courses SET studentsCache = $studentsList WHERE courseID = 3");
```

Now what if a concurrent session creates a new student while this is executing?
Does `SELECT name FROM students WHERE courseID = 3 LOCK IN SHARE MODE` also lock "future rows" that have `courseID = 3`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. If the second SQL statement depends on the result of the first, you have to use transactions.

On the other hand: It is a cache. It is supposed to contain outdated data at least some time of the day.

Comment: i'm using transaction already (which isolation level should i use?), i thought transactions would not help in this case

Comment: Transactions encapsulate a series of queries from changes made by parallel queries.